# macvim does not recognize math latex symbols anymore

Tags: macvim, filetype-tex

I am running Macvim 8.0.1633 (146) on macos 10.13.3
Weirdly, even with syntax on, the math highlighting is plain wrong:
[image: weird behavior]

Here, I didn't search for end{equation} Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: What's the output if you place the cursor on the incorrectly highlighted item and run the command: `:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")` (which echos the name of the syntax item under the cursor)?

Comment: @Rich: Dear Rich, the output is: **texBadMath** The file compiles fine and the output is correct...

Comment: Do you have the complete file available somewhere?